# When I try to flag a deleted comment I get a picture of the "page not found" page

Tags: bug, comment-flags, popups

I was trying to flag a comment, but it appears a mod (or a couple of users) were too fast for me and it was already deleted.  When I clicked "flag", instead on the nice red popup saying "comment already removed", I got a huge picture of the "page not found" page.

[image]

I have reproduced this on my site's meta as well:

[image]

If I click on it, it disappears just like any other popup...

Comment: Needs more pandas...

Comment: @animuson  *Pandas*?  I could add some freehand circles...

Comment: [Pandas](http://stackexchange.com/error) [`-->`](http://stackexchange.com/errors)

Comment: @animuson I'm afraid we don't have Pandas where I come from...  I'll add some freehand circles.  Are you sure talking error pages aren't better?

Comment: Needs more freehand circles.  In either event, this is unusual for sure - may be the error message passing through to the modal, which don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: This bug also happens on flagging comments on answers, not just question comment flags.  See this screenshot:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/75JkS.png